# Code Igniter 3 - Setting htaccess for multiple application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I have a problem to setting htaccess..
Whenever I call my website, its only available for 1 application, the other can not.

This is how my folder structure:

```
-application
  -web
  -service
-aset
-assets
-system
-.htaccess
-index.php
-service.php
```

This is my htaccess default setting (works on all version with one application) :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is, I want to make 2 application in 1 Project, so i just need to make application/web and application/service, and setting application web as default application.

I use Code Igniter 3.0.2, Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

Comment: It's only available for 1 application? What application? I'm confused.

Comment: I mean, it only can call /mysite/web, but the service application can not.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you moving your other application inside the web one.

```
-application
  -config
  -controller
  -model
  -view
  -service
    -application
      ...
    -system
    -.htaccess
    -index.php
-system
-.htaccess
-index.php
```

That would be like having a codeigniter inside a codeigniter.